# ImportError: no module named gravatar

Tags: python, django

I am using Django1.10, when I process `python manage.py migrate`.

I get:

> ImportError: no module named gravatar.

Before that, I have installed **python2.7** and run it in virtual environment, as well as **django_gravatar**.

What's the problem?

[image: the detail of command line Error]

Comment: have you added that module in installed apps?

Comment: Post text as text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate the virtual environment first. See this section of the [docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/?highlight=activate#activate-script):

In a newly created virtualenv there will also be a activate shell script. For Windows systems, activation scripts are provided for the Command Prompt and Powershell.

On Posix systems, this resides in `/ENV/bin/`, so you can run:

```
$ source bin/activate
```

For some shells (e.g. the original Bourne Shell) you may need to use the . command, when source does not exist. There are also separate activate files for some other shells, like csh and fish. bin/activate should work for `bash/zsh/dash`.

This will change your `$PATH` so its first entry is the virtualenv’s `bin/` directory. (You have to use source because it changes your shell environment in-place.) This is all it does; it’s purely a convenience. If you directly run a script or the python interpreter from the virtualenv’s bin/ directory (e.g. `path/to/ENV/bin/pip` or `/path/to/ENV/bin/python-script.py`) there’s no need for activation.

The activate script will also modify your shell prompt to indicate which environment is currently active. To disable this behaviour, see VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT.

To undo these changes to your path (and prompt), just run:

```
$ deactivate
```

On Windows, the equivalent activate script is in the Scripts folder:

```
\path\to\env\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: sorry, the problem still exists when I activate the virtual enviroment...how to solve it?